# ImageIO.read() не читает png файл

Tags: java, файлы, изображения

Метод [`ImageIO.read(file)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.File)) не может прочитать `png` файл, но может читать `jpg`.

Пример с jpg

```java
try {
    BufferedImage read = ImageIO.read(new File("asdd.jpg"));
    System.out.println(read.getHeight());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Пример с png

```java
try {
    BufferedImage read = ImageIO.read(new File("asdaa.png"));
    System.out.println(read.getHeight());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Возвращает `NullPointerException`.

Размер `png` картинки 1000 на 1000 пикселей, файл существует.

Comment: Мб jpg не поддерживается? Что выводит `ImageIO.getReaderFormatNames()`?

Comment: jpg поддерживается и работает, не работает png. getReaderFormatNames возвращает JPG
jpg
bmp
BMP
gif
GIF
WBMP
png
PNG
wbmp
jpeg
JPEG

Comment: Да, оговорился :) Интересно, а в `asdaa.png` точно PNG или мб там файл другого формата, которого нет среди поддерживаемых... Откройте тот png тестовым редактором и посмотрите первые байты. Там должно быть что-то вроде `‰PNG`

Comment: Первая строка: RIFF°  WEBPVP8 ¤  р, файл открывается

Comment: Тогда, это на самом деле https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP Забавно :)

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ходе расследования выяснилось, что на самом деле файл `asdaa.png` не **PNG**, а **WebP** (`.webp`)

А т.к. `ImageIO` не поддерживает работу с картинками этого формата, то [ImageIO.read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.File)) возвращал `null`:

> If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting
> stream, null is returned.